# unable to insert node in the binary tree

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple binary tree class with methods for inserting and deleting nodes. The insert_node method i wrote is not adding the node to the tree. I think the reference to the binary tree object is lost while inserting node with the method. Help me figure out why.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class binary_tree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.root = Node(data)

    def insert_node(self, data):
        queue = []
        queue.append(self.root)
        while queue:
            temp = queue.pop(0)
            if temp is None:
                temp = Node(data)
            else:
                queue.append(temp.left)
                queue.append(temp.right)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```
temp = Node(data)
```

Here you created new node, in order to add it to tree you should set it as `left` or `right` in its parent. In `queue` you should save parent node, while you save left and right child, so when you want to insert new node, you don't have reference to parent:

```
  parent
 /     \
left   right
```

For example, is left is `None`, you should insert new node as left for parent, but you don't keep ref to its parent, you have only `None` (left node) in your queue!

Corrected code with comments:

```
class binary_tree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.root = Node(data)

    def insert_node(self, data):
        queue = [self.root]  # start from root, it's always not None
        while queue:
            temp = queue.pop(0)  # get current parent node
            if temp.left is None:  # if left child doesn't exist, add new node as left child for parent
                temp.left = Node(data)
                return  # node added, exit
            elif temp.right is None:  # if right child doesn't exist, add new node as right child for parent
                temp.right = Node(data)
                return   # node added, exit
            else:  # both child nodes exist - add them to queue
                queue.append(temp.left)
                queue.append(temp.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-in-a-binary-tree-in-level-order/), also you can use:

```
def insert_node(self, data): 

    queue = []  
    temp = self.root
    queue.append(temp)  


    # Do level order traversal until we find  
    # an empty place.  
    while (queue):  
        temp = queue.pop(0)  

        if (not temp.left): 
            temp.left = Node(data)  
            break
        else: 
            queue.append(temp.left)  

        if (not temp.right): 
            temp.right = Node(data)  
            break
        else: 
            queue.append(temp.right)
```